How to reproduce this bar chart in LaTeX using either pgfplots or luamplib?
I'm trying to recreate the attached bar chart using LaTeX, but I'm not sure which package would be more suitable, between pgfplots and luamplib.
As you can see in the chart, there are multiple categories on the x-axis with different bar heights. One bar (Semiconductors) is highlighted in a different color, while the rest are black. The values are shown on top of the bars. Additionally, there are labels beneath each bar, and the bars are vertically aligned.


you don't really need any package at all for such a simple bar chart (other than color for the blue)

So how can I reprodce it without \pgfplots or \luamplib package. Could you show me the code?

You can always perceive a bar as a rule, narrow and high. You use, e.g., parbox-es to place text, if you want to avoid any graphics like Tikz.

It‘s always a good idea to read the, and especially this manual on pgfplots.

A start just using color package

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\fbox{%
  \setlength\unitlength{.5cm}
\begin{picture}(20,30)(0,-4)


  \put(2,0){\rule{2\unitlength}{15.4\unitlength}}
  \put(3,15.4){\makebox(0,1){15.4}}
  \put(3,-1.5){\makebox(0,1){phama and bio}}

  \put(6,0){\color{blue}\rule{2\unitlength}{14.2\unitlength}}
  \put(7,14.2){\makebox(0,1){14.2}}
  \multiput(7,0)(0,-.1){30}{\makebox(0,0){.}}
  \put(7,-4){\makebox(0,1){semiconductors}}

  \put(10,0){\rule{2\unitlength}{11.8\unitlength}}
  \put(11,11.8){\makebox(0,1){11.8}}
  \put(11,-1.5){\makebox(0,1){Software and services}}
  
\end{picture}%
}
\end{document}


If you need something that works, this is a solution. It's far from being the best... even from being good. But it will work "para salir de paso", as we say here.
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newdimen\chartcolumnunitht\chartcolumnunitht=1.5em %HT of the unit from the column.
\newdimen\chartcolumnspacefromswcorner\chartcolumnspacefromswcorner=5em %Space between SW corner of column.
\newdimen\chartcolumnlabeldeltayshift\chartcolumnlabeldeltayshift=3em %delta yshift between lower labels.
\newdimen\chartcolumnwd\chartcolumnwd=2em %wd of column
\newcount\chartcolumnnum
\newcount\chartcolumnlevel

\def\chartcolumn#1#2#3{%{ht}{lower label}{color}
    \node[fill = #3, inner sep = 0pt, minimum width = \chartcolumnwd, minimum height = #1\chartcolumnunitht, anchor = south] (C) at (\chartcolumnnum * \chartcolumnspacefromswcorner,0) {}; %THE column.
    \node[anchor = south, font = \small\sffamily] at (C.north) {#1}; %number above.
    \node[anchor = north, align = center, yshift = \chartcolumnlevel*\chartcolumnlabeldeltayshift, font = \small\sffamily] (B) at (C.south) {#2}; %label below.
    \ifnum\chartcolumnlevel<0
        \draw[gray, line width=0.75pt, shorten <=1pt, shorten >=1pt](B.north)--(C.south);%gray line
        \advance\chartcolumnlevel by 1 %switch the level of lower label.
    \else
        \advance\chartcolumnlevel by -1 %switch the level of lower label.
    \fi
    \advance\chartcolumnnum by 1 %move the column.
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \chartcolumn{15.4}{Pharmaceuticals\\ and biotechnology}{black!80!blue}
        \chartcolumn{14.2}{Semiconductors}{cyan}
        \chartcolumn{11.8}{Software and\\computer services}{black!80!blue}
        \chartcolumn{9.0}{Electronics and\\electrical equipment}{black!80!blue}
        \chartcolumn{4.8}{Automotive}{black!80!blue}
        \chartcolumn{3.8}{Healthcare systems}{black!80!blue}
        \chartcolumn{3.0}{General\\industries}{black!80!blue}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I left some things commented so you can change them as you like

